# Flutter version failed

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

The current Flutter SDK version is 1.12.13+hotfix.8.

Because flutterbuyandsell depends on provider 4.1.2 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.16.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; Because flutterbuyandsell depends on provider 4.1.2 which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.16.0, version solving failed.)

My pubspec.yaml

```
name: flutterbuyandsell
description: A new Flutter ecommerce store application.

version: 1.17.0

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.2.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
    sdk: flutter
  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  shared_preferences: 0.5.7+3
  cached_network_image: 2.2.0+1
  flutter_cache_manager: 1.2.2 #for cached_network_image
  http: 0.12.1
  provider: 4.1.2
  connectivity: 0.4.8+6
  dynamic_theme: 1.0.1
  sembast: 2.4.4+1
  path_provider: 1.6.9
  intl: 0.16.1
  shimmer: 1.1.1
  smooth_star_rating: 1.1.1
  url_launcher: 5.4.10
  carousel_slider: 2.1.0
  firebase_core: 0.4.5
  firebase_messaging: 6.0.16
  firebase_auth: 0.16.1 # firebase_auth is for phone login
  admob_flutter: 0.3.4
  firebase_database: 3.1.6
  google_sign_in: 4.5.1
  flutter_facebook_login: 3.0.0
  photo_view: 0.9.2
  progress_dialog: 1.2.3
  braintree_payment: 1.2.4
  easy_localization: 2.3.2
  launch_review: 2.0.0
  package_info: 0.4.0+18
  flutter_icons: 1.1.0
  stripe_payment: 1.0.7
  flutter_credit_card: 0.1.3
  fluttertoast: 4.0.1
  permission_handler: 5.0.0+hotfix.6
  flutter_map: 0.9.0
  latlong: 0.6.1
  geocoder: 0.2.1
  multi_image_picker: 4.6.7
  flutter_widget_from_html: 0.3.3+4
  esys_flutter_share: 1.0.2
  apple_sign_in: 0.1.0



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  #flutter_local_notifications:
  #  path: lib/utils/local_noti/


# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  assets:
   - assets/images/placeholder_circle_image.png
   - assets/images/placeholder_image.png
   - assets/langs/ar-DZ.json
   - assets/langs/en-US.json
   - assets/langs/hi-IN.json
   - assets/langs/de-DE.json
   - assets/langs/es-ES.json
   - assets/langs/fr-FR.json
   - assets/langs/id-ID.json
   - assets/langs/it-IT.json
   - assets/langs/ja-JP.json
   - assets/langs/ko-KR.json
   - assets/langs/ms-MY.json
   - assets/langs/pt-PT.json
   - assets/langs/ru-RU.json
   - assets/langs/th-TH.json
   - assets/langs/tr-TR.json
   - assets/langs/zh-CN.json
   - assets/images/verify_email_icon.jpg
   - assets/images/down.png
   - assets/images/baesline_access_time_black_24.png
   - assets/images/baseline_check_green_24.png
   - assets/images/baseline_graph_black_24.png
   - assets/images/baseline_price_down_black_24.png
   - assets/images/baseline_price_up_black_24.png
   - assets/images/baseline_empty_item_grey_24.png
   - assets/images/home_icon/discount_products.png
   - assets/images/home_icon/easy_payment.png
   - assets/images/home_icon/featured_products.png
   - assets/images/home_icon/free_download.png
   - assets/images/trending.png
   - assets/images/flutter_buy_and_sell_logo.png
   - assets/images/flutter_buy_and_sell_logo_light.png
   - assets/images/baseline_pin_black_24.png
   - assets/images/baseline_favourite_grey_24.png
   - assets/images/default_image.png
   - assets/images/baseline_promotion_color_74.png
  fonts:
    - family: Product Sans
      fonts:
        - asset: assets/fonts/Product-Sans-Regular.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Product-Sans-Bold-Italic.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Product-Sans-Bold.ttf
        - asset: assets/fonts/Product-Sans-Italic.ttf
```

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of flutter on the stable channel is 1.17.3 and higher on the other channels. You have likely not upgraded flutter since this release. Use `flutter upgrade` to remediate your issue.